# A database system for stat counting

Tags: mysql, database, nosql, aggregation, counting

My server generates huge amounts of transaction logs. Each record contains information about the referer URL, the user, the manufacturer and the related product. An example record might be as follows:

```
{transaction_id: 1, url: "http://example.com/", user_agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7", manufacturer_id: 2, product_id: 3}
```

I store these logs only for a month, then I discard the old ones to make room for the new ones.

What I need is to answer questions like "How many times was Product-3 displayed on URL http://example.com/ each day?" or "How many times did a user with Firefox 10 requested a product of Manufacturer-2 each day?". All reports are daily, but the ways of grouping may increase in time. Also, I should be able to store the data for years.

**What database system do you recommend to aggregate logs in flexible ways?**

I considered,

- **MySQL**: Storage friendly and easy to archive, but requires altering tables and rewriting queries each time an aggregation was changed.
- **CouchDB**: Map-reduce approach is nice, but its revision system is not suitable for counting(isn't it?).
- **Redis**: Perfect for in-memory counting, but is hard to query and needs to fit all data to the memory.
- **MongoDB**: Easy to create new types of aggregations and perfect for on-disk counting, but it doesn't seem that much storage friendly and it doesn't seem as stable as MySQL and CouchDB either.

I am inclined towards MongoDB. What do you think?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use existing software that goes through your logs and shows statistics - something like AWStats maybe?

Comment: @Grim... The logs are generated by server for each transaction, rather than each request (I should've pointed this out), and there are custom fields such as manufacturer_id and product_id which are not stored in the URL. I may check how AWStats work though. Thanks!

Comment: There are many different stats packages (and many can handle custom fields nicely), and it may be a better solution that rolling your own. Only you know that answer to that, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into Bigtable-like databases. Currently, there are two open-source implementations: HBase and Hypertable. (Disclaimer: i work for Hypertable). Analytics is a typical usage scenario.

In case of Hypertable, you get

- automatic timestamps for each inserted row
- rows with a certain configurable age (i.e. 1 month) will be deleted automatically
- a query language (similar to SQL)

I'm sure HBase offers similar functionality.

Have a look at this tutorial - it shows how to query logs of web visitors by specifying time intervals and other predicates.
http://code.google.com/p/hypertable/wiki/HQLTutorial

Comment: Thank you. I did a quick research on BigTable like systems. I wonder, how do these systems compare with MongoDB on a non-distributed environment, i.e. on a single machine?

Comment: I don't know how they compare, but i know that they work. Hypertable can run on a single machine. And both (Hypertable and HBase) can run on a single-machine hadoop (pseudo-)cluster. And if you want to scale then you just add another machine to this cluster.